# buggy margin behavior with dynamically resizing UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitextview

I need a dynamically resizing UITextView but the right margin encroaches towards the left alarmingly after numerous resizes so that a very narrow strip of text is shown with lots of white space in the text view. This can be reproduced by a simple setup with just a UITextView and UISlider. A simple sample setup that produces this behavior is UISlider with value range from 0-200, a UITextView of 320 width and this code:

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider {
    textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320 - slider.value, 300);
}
```

Some things I've tried are tinkering with the autoResizingMask, contentMode, contentOffset, and sizeToFit but none of them work. How can this weird behavior be avoided, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 4):

Subclass `UITextView` and override `layoutSubViews` to set the `frame` to `CGRectZero` and then back to original frame size. It's not elegant but it works.

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect rect = [self frame];
    [self setFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self setFrame:rect];
}
```

Comment: This works indeed. Also works: setting textView.frame = CGRectZero before setting needed frame. (in this case before: textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320 - slider.value, 300); ).

Comment: Awesome.  Been looking for this for a while!