# UIMenuController menu disappears automatically when there are multiple UITextView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, uimenucontroller

I'm trying to make UIMenuController to display copy&paste menu when the UITextView got long pressed. It works if there is only one UITextView on the screen. However, if there are multiple UITextViews on the screen, long press on the active UITextView (The one is the firstResponder) triggers magnifying glass to be shown, when finger is released, the copy&paste menu is displayed, however, the menu is dismissed automatically in less than one second.

The following is the view hierarchy:
UIView -> UIImageView -> MyUIView -> UITextView
                                   |**__**> MyUIView -> UITextView

I set userInteractionEnabled and editable of non-active UITextViews to NO. Any idea on how to make the copy&paste menu stay?

I am using Xcode 4.6.3 and test it on iPhone 4S with iOS 7.0

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, whenever there's a change in firstResponder, UIMenuController gets dismissed!

In order to track the source of the change, if other, you can listen to UIMenuControllerWillHideMenuNotification and check who's dismissing the menu.

Comment: How do you check who is dismissing the menu.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I didn't have enough details in the question, that's probably why there was no answers.

The key missing piece is that I subclassed UITextView and it overrides layoutSubviews (see [buggy margin behavior with dynamically resizing UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305159/buggy-margin-behavior-with-dynamically-resizing-uitextview)). The solution is simply removing layoutSubviews function, and I used  krafter's suggestion to address UITextView cut off issue.